# android studio does not show ANDROID section in the picture below on the left

Tags: dart, flutter-layout

[image]

android not showing partition

android studio don't show android park for me.
my english is very little sorry

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. If you want the android part, you can open the "android" folder as a new project.

In the Android Studio menu, go to "File > Open...", then browse to your project, and select the "Android" subfolder:

[image: open dialog]

Then click "Open".